# ignore spaces within/around brackets to count occurrences

Tags: bash, awk, grep

**(to LaTeX users)** I want to search for manually labeled items

**(to whom it may concern)** [script file on GitHub](https://github.com/tmelorc/delimctr)

I tried to find solution, but what I've found suggested to remove spaces first. In my case, I think there should be simpler solution. It could be using `grep` or `awk` or some other tool.

Consider the following lines:

```
\item[a)] some text
\item [i) ] any text
\item[ i)] foo and faa
\item [   1) ] foo again
```

I want to find (or count) if there are items with a single `)` inside brackets. The format could have blank spaces inside the brackets and/or around it. Also, the char before the closing parentheses could be any letter or number.

**Edit:** I tried `grep "\[a)\]"` but it missed `[ a) ]`. 
Since there are many possible ways to write an item, I can not decide about a possible pattern. I think that it is enough for me such as

```
\item<blank spaces>[<blank spaces><letter or number>)<blank spaces>]
```

Replace blank space could not work because the patter above in general contains text around it (for example: `\item[ a)] consider the function...`)

The output should indicate is there are such patterns or not. It could be zero or the number of occurrences.

Comment: To be clear, you are looking for anything containing the word `item`, `[` and `]`?

Comment: Please be clear what is the expected output?

Comment: @Jason, I think not *anything*. Can not appear letters between `\item` and `[`, for example. Also, inside the brackets, only spaces and some format for enumarate, for example, `i)` for roman numbers, etc...

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, done! I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to do it all in the `grep` itself:

```
grep -c -E '\\item\s*\[\s*\w+\)\s*\]' file.txt
```

Note all the `\s*` checks for spaces. Also `-c` to get the count.

Breaking it down:

```
\\       a backslash (needs escape in grep)
item     "item"
\s*      optional whitespaces
\[       "[" (needs escape in -E)
\s*      optional whitespaces 
\w+      at least one 'word' char
\)       ")" (needs escape in -E)
\s*      optional whitespaces 
\]       "]" (needs escape in -E)
```

Comment: So, is `[0-9A-Za-z]` not necessary?!

Comment: I have used 'not space or bracket' as my expression, instead. You could actually use '\w' for 'word character', in fact I changed it now to '\w'

Answer (score 1):

So I am thinking something like this:

```
tr -d " \t" < file.txt | grep -c '\\item\[[0-9A-Za-z])\]'
```

This will count the number of matches for you.

Edit: Added `\t` to tr call.  Now removes all spaces and tabs.

Here is a grep only version.  This could be useful for printing out all of the matches (by removing -c) as well since the above version modifies the input:

```
grep -c '\\item *\[ *[0-9A-Za-z]) *\]' file.txt
```

Here is a more versatile answer if this is what you looking for. Here, we output the matches to a file and count the lines from the file to get the number of matches...

```
grep '\\item *\[ *[0-9A-Za-z]) *\]' file.txt > matches.txt
wc -l < matches.txt
```

Comment: Is `tr` recommended for big files with a lot of lines and words?

Comment: Yes it is fine.  It is simply removing the spaces.   It is not, however, removing them from the file.  It is only removing spaces from the `stdin` for `grep`.  Your file will remain untouched.

Comment: It is removing the spaces so the grep can be simpler

Comment: @GemTaylor, simpler?! How?

Comment: I am just writing up the more complex grep. Patience!

Comment: @GemTaylor, sorry. You said *simpler*, so I supposed it would be short command. I'll wait.

Comment: No, this is the simpler version, because tr has already discarded all the spaces, so grep doesn't deal with them, but it invokes 3 different commands to do 1 job.

Comment: Now it only invokes 2 =D

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may also help here(I am simply removing the spaces between `[` to `]` and then looking for pattern of either digit or character in it.

```
awk '
match($0,/\[.*\]/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",val);
  if(val ~ /[a-z0-9]+\)/){  count++  }
}
END{
  print count
}'  Input_file
```